# pipenv, pip not found following python3 update

Tags: debian, python, python3

I am running Debian bullseye/sid and recently updated to Debian unstable to experiment with the Sway windows manager. This went fine until I updated to a more recent version of python. My python3 is currently version 3.7.4.

Since updating, I can no longer import pipenv or pip and some other global packages are missing.

```
$ pipenv shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/pipenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pipenv import cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipenv'
```

In /usr/bin I have python2.7, python3.5, and python3.7. Pip is installed: "which pip" reads "/usr/bin/pip". I installed pipenv as a user installation (pip install --user pipenv). The binary is present.

Can anbody give me pointers on how best to investigate this problem?

edit: **hm, in addition to updating, I also changed the default python version**:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```

This is [not advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt), and, since I almost invariably work in venvs, would have made little difference to me even if it were so problematic. Before holidays I do dumb stuff ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it ought to have been obvious, but the following resolved this problem. An apt search returns two versions of pip. I had assumed, but not checked, that the system-wide version of python I was running was 3.x and so had overlooked the following. Typically, I had been working in venvs most of the time.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

I then reinstalled pipenv as a [user install](https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv):

```
$ pip install --user pipenv
```

Which left me only to install a specific version of py3status to satisfy a dependency as debian unstable was overshooting it:

```
$ pip install py3tatus==3.16
```

If there is a more elegant or pythonic way of doing this, I'd be glad to hear of it, but this seems close enough for rock 'n' roll.

edit: see edit above for important context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your pip and/or pipenv? Since you've updated to a newer version, it might mean that your packages need updating too (to be compatible).  Try adding the version number after your `pip` commands (e.g `pip3` - which I use). In these cases, if you used `pip` (since it's a later version and so you wouldn't have installed it, then using it to install a package will not work. Either way, you may need to install pip3 or update to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've had no major issues to date but it is true that my system-wide pip is 2.7. I have various venvs set up on either pipenv or with pip3. Probably, the above points to a wider issue touching on [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) territory so I'm getting my head around that piecemeal.

Comment: @krozruch If the answer worked for you, please upvote so others may use this information in the future!